# Detect repetition in sound file

Tags: algorithm, audio

I really have no idea if what I'm thinking is feasible, but what the heck.

I have some MP3s of game music. This game music was rendered from a Tracker format, which means that at some point the track loops back to an earlier point, so it's like this:

```
Intro---|Main loop-------------------|Main loop-------------------|Main loop fade|
```

Or in "regex" form:

```
/^\p{Intro}(\p{Main_0}\p{Main_1}\p{Main_2})+\p{Main_0}\p{Main_1_fading}$/
```

I hope this communicates what's going on!

Basically, I want to know if I can detect the start and end of the main loop based on repetition of the waveform. The idea being that since they are rendered from a tracker format, the waveform should be exactly the same between loops, even after having been "baked" in MP3 format.

If this is possible, how might I go about finding such a repeating loop? The goal is to programmatically extend these looping tracks to repeat more times, so I don't have to do it manually.

At this stage I'm simply looking for general algorithms to approach the problem. I can work out how to read an MP3 file's waveform, process it and save a new one without difficulty, what I need help with here is **how to find a repeating portion** of the waveform. Does anyone have any wisdom to impart?

Comment: Interesting question! Would [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/find-the-longest-repeated-pattern-in-a-string) maybe be of use?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele It might be, if the answer included the algorithm used rather than a link to something that yields a 403 :D

Comment: Oh, perhaps I should have clicked that link too ;) Anyway, it seems that even on the highest abstraction level (you can somehow map sound samples to a fixed-size alphabet, so your wav file reduces to a string), this is a rather difficult problem.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the max. peaks of the [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)-function should help you finding repetitions in a signal.

Answer (score 2):

If you first perform an FFT on it to convert it to the frequency domain it will be less sensitive to sample alignment and changes in amplitude.

Optionally apply some filtering to get the key frequencies that matter and filter out the ones that don't (e.g. additional noises someone's added over the repeat might be something you can filter out).

Finally apply autocorrelation as Frank mentions to find the repeats.